# Row average of columns that match long string with no specific pattern

Tags: r

I have a dataset with hundreds of columns. I would like to take the average of columns ending with _lh and _rh that have the same string before the underscore and add a new column with the average like this:

srmdis_fdsa = srmdis_fdsa_lh + srmdis_fdsa_rh / 2

I also have other columns in the dataset with underscore but without _lh or _rh which is making it hard for me to come up with a method.

Sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame (srmdis_fdsa_lh = runif(5),
                  srmdis_fdsa_rh =  runif(5),
                  abcds_weere_lh =  runif(5),
                  abcds_weere_rh =  runif(5),
                  kcjdi_jfdasdw_lh = runif(5),
                  kcjdi_jfdasdw_rh = runif(5),
                  icdks_djgf = runif(5),
                  izld_aqhe = runif(5))
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to loop over columns that ends_with `_lh` with `cur_column()` then replace `_lh` with `_rh` then use `get` to get the value and apply the addition with dividing by 2 and Use the.names argument to get the names:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with('_lh'),
                ~ (. + get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'lh', 'rh')))/2, 
                .names = "mean_{str_remove(.col, fixed('_lh'))}"))
```

```
  srmdis_fdsa_lh srmdis_fdsa_rh abcds_weere_lh abcds_weere_rh kcjdi_jfdasdw_lh kcjdi_jfdasdw_rh icdks_djgf  izld_aqhe mean_srmdis_fdsa mean_abcds_weere mean_kcjdi_jfdasdw
1     0.41330541      0.8128527      0.2818117     0.06078222       0.50837063        0.6864904  0.1462821 0.09663374        0.6130790        0.1712969          0.5974305
2     0.01836408      0.8541000      0.6667052     0.96903886       0.33749500        0.2258184  0.8227174 0.02199372        0.4362320        0.8178720          0.2816567
3     0.56673408      0.3678959      0.9773836     0.12023713       0.89433463        0.3184946  0.3309978 0.99304478        0.4673150        0.5488104          0.6064146
4     0.49006345      0.8739499      0.5827397     0.08836330       0.03197163        0.1739838  0.3741694 0.58393885        0.6820067        0.3355515          0.1029777
5     0.87867402      0.1513382      0.5265901     0.88076411       0.23722970        0.8014296  0.6297454 0.78182307        0.5150061        0.7036771          0.5193296
```

**or we could use multiple `across`:**

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('lh'),  .names = "mean_{str_remove(.col, '_lh')}")
         + across(ends_with('rh')),
         across(starts_with("mean"), ~ . / 2)
         )
```